# Cloned WordPress site behaving differently from original

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress-based website has been developed on an Amazon AWS AMI instance. Let's refer to that site as `http://example.com`. For the purpose of testing changes to the site, from the Amazon AWS EC2 control panel, I stopped the running instance, created an image of it, and then launched a new instance using that image. I created a DNS record for `clone.example.com` and pointed that to the cloned instance.

Once the clone instance launched, I did the following:

1. Created a new LetsEncrypt certificate for `clone.example.com` and updated `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` accordingly.
2. Using mySql Workbench, downloaded a copy of the database and removed the schema
3. Edited the database file, changing all instances of `http{s}://example.com` to `http{s}://clone.example.com`
4. Uploaded the database into a new schema with the same name
5. Searched all files in `/var/www/html` for the string `example.com` but did not find it anyplace that matters

I was then able to access the cloned site, the security certificate worked, but the site is different from the original. By different, certain colors, layouts, etc., are not the same.

The WordPress site in questions used a variety of plugins, including:

- BuddyPress and several affiliated plugins
- BP Portfolio
- Gravity Forms
- WooCommerse and several affiliated plugins

Can you please suggest what I can try to get the cloned site to behave like the original? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dug in and figure this out the hard way - I changed each instance of `https://example.com` to `https://clone.example.com` until I found the one that broke the site.

The problem was in the table `wp_options` (not surprising) and the entry that caused the problems was `social_portfolio_options`. This is a case of laziness on the developers' part - instead of doing the right thing, i.e., creating a table to store the options; they used a long string with each part being delimited by its length. Thus, changing the URL caused the string parsing to break.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered facing a similar issue relating to CSS while cloning a wordpress site months ago. However, this wasn't done on AWS but on another hosting provider. What happened was that the `page-id` on my cloned site was new and different from the one used previously. The issue was resolved after updating onto the existing styles.css with the new `page-id`.

*This is not an answer. I wanted to leave it as a comment but lacked the reputation.*

Comment: kenmistry - thanks for the suggestion. I just looked and saw that the page has the same `page-id` on both sites.